# Find row that is not null and older than 10 minutes

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am trying to find all rows that are older 10 minutes, and that are not equal 0 or null. I am writing this wrong it seems.

```
SELECT * FROM locked_users WHERE lockset < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 600) AND IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to add `lockset` in the second condition to make it work.

```
SELECT  *   
FROM    locked_users 
WHERE   lockset < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 600) AND 
        lockset IS NOT NULL AND
        lockset <> 0
```

Comment: I actually tried this as well, but there is a 0 written to the db.. I don't want it to return if there is a 0 or is null